# postgres sql datetime difference returns date but for oracle it returns the numeric value

Tags: database, oracle11g

I am doing arithmetic on date fields in postgres and oracle on the same project. I found that

`Round( DateField1 - DateField2 )` , in oracle return value  is numeric

`( DateField1 - DateField2 )` , in postgres return value  is date

for instance

`select  now() - now()` = return value is date  in postgres
and

`select sysdate - sysdate from dual` on oracle return the numeric output. And I am applying the round on the return value afterwords.

some other examples are

`select now() - to_date('15/01/204','dd/mm/yyyy')` in postgres returns date

`select round(sysdate -  to_date('15/01/204','dd/mm/yyyy') ,2)  from dual` return number in oracle

Is there any settings involved to get the numeric value in postgres or what the possible solution could be with minimum syntax changes.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.

Comment: What is the exact column type/data type of the DateField?

Comment: Wha? No, it doesn't. Please show the *actual query you ran*, or better, a stand-alone query.

Comment: Are you using some kind of middleware, query generator, ORM, etc that might be doing query transformations?

What's the actual, exact, literal SQL executed?

PostgreSQL version? ("`SELECT VERSION()`")

Comment: post is updated as per the issue causes.

Comment: Next time, please make sure your question includes PostgreSQL version *as `select version()`, not a tag*, and the *actual queries you run* on the *actual data they run on* from the beginning, otherwise I land up wasting time like this. Your columns aren't dates, they're timestamps. You were *assuming* they were dates, and incorrectly explaining the problem because of that, instead of just *showing what the problem is in the question*. You still are, because you're still saying you get a date result when you don't, you're really getting an interval. Why do you think it's date?

Comment: embracing postgres now a days and finding lot of things to cope with ,  its very nice to have adetailed response. Making Oracle executable queries to work the same on postgres requires a lot of efforts and handling  date time stuff is taking much time . If you have and can share some document that compares oracle and postgres functions and usages. Thanks

Comment: @irfanMunir As I don't work Oracle, I can't help you with that bit. Maybe start with http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#Oracle . And contribute more, so others have better resources to learn from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `round` that accepts timestamp or date arguments, nor any that returns date or timestamp:

```
regress=> \df round
                          List of functions
   Schema   | Name  | Result data type | Argument data types |  Type  
------------+-------+------------------+---------------------+--------
 pg_catalog | round | double precision | double precision    | normal
 pg_catalog | round | numeric          | numeric             | normal
 pg_catalog | round | numeric          | numeric, integer    | normal
(3 rows)
```

so either someone created one in your database (in which case all bets are off) or you've misunderstood what's going on. Without the actual SQL and the data behind it visible I can't say what's going on for sure, but what *isn't* going on is `round` returning a date.

Maybe some middleware / ORM / query generator you're using is doing something insane?

Here's what happens if you subtract two dates:

```
regress=> SELECT DATE '2013-05-01' - DATE '2013-02-01';
 ?column? 
----------
       89
(1 row)
```

You get the days between them, with type::

```
regress=> SELECT pg_typeof(DATE '2013-05-01' - DATE '2013-02-01');
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 integer
(1 row)
```

Rounding the result will cast the input to `double precision` or `numeric` and return a matching result:

```
regress=> SELECT round(DATE '2013-05-01' - DATE '2013-02-01'), 
                 pg_typeof(round(DATE '2013-05-01' - DATE '2013-02-01'));
 round |    pg_typeof     
-------+------------------
    89 | double precision
(1 row)
```

So ... no date results here.

---

After update:

You're not working with *dates*, you are working with *timestamps*. That's why *you must always provide real code in your questions*.

The short version: You're not getting dates, you're getting *intervals*. Please read the documentation:

- [Date/time types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html)
- [Date/time operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

Subtracting `timestamp` doesn't produce `date` either, though. I cannot understand why you think you are getting a date, there's never any `date` produced. You really need to show your results and why you think they're dates.

Your example:

```
select now() - to_date('15/01/204','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

is a subtraction of `date` from `timestamp`. If you weren't sure you could read the manual to see what `now()` was, or use `pg_typeof(now())`. It reports that `now()` has type `timestamp with time zone`.

So you're subtracting a date from a timestamp.

This produces an `interval`, [exactly as per the documentation on date/time operators and functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html):

> timestamp '2001-09-29 03:00' - timestamp '2001-09-27 12:00'     (produces)   interval '1 day 15:00:00'

(A `date` gets upcast to `timestamp` when subtracted from a `timestamp`, much like subtracting `int4` from `int8` causes the `int4` to get upcast to `int8` first).

So. Timestamp subtraction produces an `interval`. See:

```
regress=> select now() - to_date('15/01/204','dd/mm/yyyy');
          ?column?           
-----------------------------
 661098 days 09:09:22.293309
(1 row)
```

If you want just the days, you can either do `date` subtraction in the first place, using `current_date` instead of `now()`:

```
regress=> select current_date - to_date('15/01/204','dd/mm/yyyy');
 ?column? 
----------
   661098
(1 row)
```

... or use existing well-documented methods to get the day count from the interval. It's simpler to just subtract dates.

BTW, instead of `now()` please use `current_timestamp` (when you want a timestamp) or `current_date` (When you want a date)`. It makes readers' eyes happier.

Comment: @irfanMunir Answer updated. There is a single simple change you can make to resolve the issue you see, and I've explained it in the update, along with why this is happening and how you can avoid similar problems.